# read two byte from a hexadecimal file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to read two bytes from the hexadecimal file. The file looks like:

```
FFFFCF33
FFFF9E67
00003CCF
0000799F
FFFFF33E
FFFFE67D
FFFFCCFA
```

I have this code; the code gives me the output which I want:

```
FF
FF
CF
33
```

I want to modify this code to make more automate that I don't need to calculate the range of the loop. The loop works at the end of the file.

Any Solution!!

```
#!/usr/bin/ python
import time
with open('remove-spaces-and-access-element-by-element.txt','r') as binary_file:     
    data=binary_file.read()
    hexdata=data
    print (hexdata)

    for i in range (0,108,9):
        binary_file.seek(i)
        byte1=binary_file.read(2)
        byte2=binary_file.read(2)
        byte3=binary_file.read(2)
        byte4=binary_file.read(2)
        final_byte= byte1 +'\n'+ byte2 +'\n'+ byte3 +'\n'+ byte4 
        print final_byte

        #print 'i=', i
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly

Comment: Also, the loop in the code does not seem to work with the provided input.

Comment: how do you calculate the range? E.g., is it an external input, or use full file content?

Comment: The code works the I just showed the random output from the screen.

Comment: How is the random output going to help us understand your intentions?

Comment: Range calculation is simple to get four byte loop starts from zero to eight Nine in decimal so each after 9 it  gives me four bytes.

Comment: I have modified the output

Comment: Looks like you want to apply the same operation to _each line_ in your hex dump, is this correct?

Comment: Yes . I want to apply  the same operation on each line. @DYZ

Comment: So, why not organize a loop `for line in binary_file:`, strip the newline from each line, take four 2-character slices from each line, and print each on a separate output line?

Comment: for line in binary_file(): take the whole file at once than you can't strip it. If you want to strip, need to open it as a readlines() but in this case  binary_file.read(2) didn't work